# Performance Testing Tool That Can Produce a Graph

Tags: performance, testing, performance-testing

Is anybody know a good testing tool that can produce a graph containing the CPU cycle and RAM usage?

What I will do for ex. is I will run an application and while the application is running the testing tool will record CPU cycle and RAM Usage and it will make a graph as an output.

Basically what I'm trying to test is how much heavy load an application put on RAM and CPU.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case this is Windows the easiest way is probably Performance Monitor (perfmon.exe).

You can configure the counters you are interested in (Such as Processor Time/Commited Bytes/et) and create a Data Collector Set that measures these counters at the desired interval. There are even templates for basic System Performance Report or you can add counters for the particular process you are interested in.

You can schedule the time where you want to execute the sampling and you will be able to see the result using PerfMon or export to a file for further processing.

Video tutorial for the basics: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=591kfPROYbs

Good Sample where it shows how to monitor SQL:
http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2006/12/dba-101-using-perfmon-for-sql-performance-tuning/

Answer (score 0):

Loadrunner is the best I can think of ; but its very expensive too ! Depending on what you are trying to do, there might be cheaper alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Any tool which can either hook to the standard Windows or 'NIX system utilities can do this.    This has been a defacto feature set on just about every commercial tool for the past 15 years (HP, IBM, Microfocus, etc).   Some of the web only commercial tools (but not all) and the hosted services offer this as wekll.  For the hosted services you will generally need to punch a hole through your firewall for them to get access to the hosts for monitoring purposes.

On the open source fron this is a totally mixed bag.  Some have it, some don't.  Some support one platform, but not others (i.e. support Windows, but not 'NIX or vice-versa).

What tools are you using?  It is unfortunately common for people to have performance tools in use and not be aware of their existing toolset's monitoring capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

All of the major commercial performance testing tools have this capability, as well as a fair number of the open source ones.   The ability to integrate monitor data with response time data is key to the identification of bottlenecks in the system.

If you have a commercial tool and your staff is telling you that it cannot be done then what they are really telling you is that they don't know how to do this with the tool that you have.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using jmeter, once you install the agent in the target machine you just need to add the perfmon monitor to your test plan.

- It will produce 2 result files, the pefmon file and the requests log.
- You could also build a plot that compares the resource compsumtion to the load, and througput. The throughput stops increasing when some resource capacity is exceeded. As you can see in the image CPU time increases as the load increases.

[image]

- JMeter perfmon plugin: http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but I was looking for the same thing today and as I did not found something that was simple to use and produced graphs I made this helper program for apachebench:

https://github.com/juanluisbaptiste/apachebench-graphs

It will run apachebench and plot the results and percentile files using gnuplot.

I hope it helps someone.